# pseudoclass :first-child not working

Tags: html, css, sass, pseudo-class

Am I doing something wrong?

css/sass:

```
#section
  article
   border-top: 1px solid black
   &:first-child
     border: none !important
```

html/haml:

```
#section
  %h2 title
   %article
    stuff here. There is still a top border here despite first-child style.
   %article
    stuff here.
   %article
    stuff here.
```

This doesn't work, and there is still a border on the first `<article>`.  I have to make another class and do something like `article.noborder` on the first article to get no border.  Any help would be appreciated...css hates me.

Comment: The thing you're doing wrong is misunderstanding `:first-child`. `article:first-child` doesn't mean "match the first `article` element", it means "match the first child **if** it's an `article` element" - in this case the first child is a `h2`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) because of the `h2` preceding the first `article`.

Comment: thanks! yeah I had a feeling it was cuz of the h2, but wasn't sure what to look up.

Comment: This works.

The ~ will select all elements except the first one.

in my case 
.row .row { margin-top: 0px; }
.row ~ .row { margin-top: 10px; }

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the H2 is the first child of the section, not the first article.

Answer (score 1):

```
section article:first-child{
  border:none;
}

section article:nth-child(2){
  border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

I meet this issue before, try to remember that don't use different way to call the same elements.

If you use `body section article { border:2px solid yellow}` will overlap the
`section article:first-child{...}` because the former one is more specific.